# MAVEN maxheapsize doesn't change (JAVA 11 & CENTOS 7)

Tags: java, maven, centos

I've been trying to build a maven project using JAVA 11 on CentOS 7.

When ran "**mvn clean install**" at the first time, I got an error

> Error assembling JAR: Problem creating jar: Execution exception: Java
>   heap space

So, I've been try to search for solutions on the internet. I've found that a lot of people do like

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m"
```

And it's working. Then, I tried this solution and build the project again. But it's not working. It still shows the same error. There's an info log shows "**Final Memory: 218M/239M**".

I tried export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m" a lot of time but it's not working.

After that, I've found that we can check the maxHeapSize by using command

> java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep HeapSize

I got **size_t MaxHeapSize = 260046848**

It seems like the command **MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m"** doesn't work normally. Or I did something wrong. Please help.

Comment: First which Maven version, which plugins version do you use?

Comment: @khmarbaise 
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>

Comment: First that's not answering my question. exec-maven-plugin is not responsible for creating JAR ...and which Maven version? etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

I just need to do the

> export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m"

by root user. I need to add **sudo** before using the command.

> sudo export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m"